# In Kivy, is there a way to dynamically change the shape of a texture?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a scientific visualization tool using Kivy in which I display a set of 2D data to the user. Essentially, I create a texture with the same size as my data set using something like `my_texture = Texture.create(size=(my_data_x, my_data_y))`. I use `my_texture.blit_buffer(Data_set)` to blit it onto the canvas and display it and it all works great. The problem is: I want to allow the user to be able to change the size of the data set while the program is running. Since the data size is changing, I need to have a texture that also has the new size. I've tried reassigning the `my_texture` variable to a newly created texture, but what's actually being shown on the screen is the texture right before the change.

So my question is: is there a way to appropriately create textures after my program is already running and get them to display on the canvas, or do textures always have to be generated on startup? Alternatively, is there a way I can reshape an already existing texture?

Answer (score 0):

[Reloading the Texture](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#reloading-the-texture)

> If the OpenGL context is lost, the Texture must be reloaded. Textures
>   that have a source are automatically reloaded but ***generated
>   textures must be reloaded by the user***.
>
> Use the Texture.add_reload_observer() to add a reloading function that
>   will be automatically called when needed:
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, **kwargs):
>     super(...).__init__(**kwargs)
>     self.texture = Texture.create(size=(512, 512), colorfmt='RGB',
>         bufferfmt='ubyte')
>     self.texture.add_reload_observer(self.populate_texture)
>
>     # and load the data now.
>     self.cbuffer = '\x00\xf0\xff' * 512 * 512
>     self.populate_texture(self.texture)
>
> def populate_texture(self, texture):
>     texture.blit_buffer(self.cbuffer)
> ```
>
> This way, you can use the same method for initialization and
>   reloading.
>
> **Note**
>
> For all text rendering with our core text renderer, the texture is
>   generated but we already bind a method to redo the text rendering and
>   reupload the text to the texture. You don’t have to do anything.